# ((GRUB @ Debian 11) : dual boot with Windows 7) @ ((UEFI + GPT) SSD)

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot, grub

I followed the official instructions on how to correctly build a dual-boot system from scratch:

> https://wiki.debian.org/DualBoot/Windows :
>
> UEFI + GPT Solves Everything
>
> If your machine comes with UEFI, it is recommended to format the entire disk in GPT before you install any operating systems on it. With UEFI + GPT, Windows Boot Manager and GRUB are isolated and re-installing Windows (or upgrading it to another version) will not rewrite GRUB records on the disk. And because of this, the installation order of this 2 systems also does not matter at all.

Turns out that it's not so simple as the official instructions says, unfortunately. Two days later, `GRUB` vanished and Windows 7 was the only boot choice.

On the official `#debian` IRC channel, someone told me to make a `Rescatux` thumb drive, and I tried it. I was able to reinstall `GRUB` on the partition that has Debian 11, and this made `GRUB` reappear on the motherboard 'boot override' menu (`F8` on this case, but normally `F12` on other motherboards), without Windows listed on it. So the motherboard gave me the option to boot into the `Windows Bootloader` or into `GRUB`, if I pressed `F8`. But, shortly after, `GRUB` disappeared again.

So: which is the best way to make `GRUB` stay as a boot option, and have Windows on it too?

Comment: Is this an HP (F9 typically HP)? Grub and user use efibootmgr to set boot order in UEFI. And with  everybody but HP that works. But many posters with HP have said they could only change boot order by going into UEFI settings F10 and changing order in boot tab. Some have also had to update UEFI firmware which should be current due to potential Spectre virus. A new one was just found July 2022 in many InsydeH2O UEFI firmware.

Comment: @oldfred Not an HP, it's a normal PC with an ASUS motherboard.

Comment: You then should be able to use efibootmgr to change boot order, or use UEFI settings. https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr What model Asus. My z97 Asus needed multiple UEFI settings. Asus-ar screenshots oldfred
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258575&page=2  If still issues. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred My ASUS is: `M5A97 LE R2.0 rev 1.00`.

Comment: Do not know AMD, but my Intel Z97 should have similar UEFI settings. But as early UEFI, have you updated UEFI to latest available which still is older. Some with early UEFI, found BIOS installs easier as UEFI was so buggy. Linux had to find many work arounds and vendors had to do many UEFI/BIOS updates. UEFI should now work.

Comment: @oldfred By suggesting `efiboomgr`, are you telling me to not use `Rescatux`?

Comment: I have used Supergrub. Do not know Rescatux, but expect it to work well. I also have used rEFInd for UEFI boot when I had an issue. If booting with UEFI, you can use efibootmgr to change UEFI settings which is separate from boot loader like grub2 or emergency boot loaders.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows will continue breaking GRUB every time it installs an update, crashes, or just wants to break GRUB.

The solution is to have 2 SSDs, one for each OS, so Windows cannot mess with Linux.

NO DUAL BOOT AT ALL.

Comment: You may also run one OS in a VM on top of the other OS.

Comment: @Kusalananda That would trash the performance of the system.

Comment: This obviously depends on what you're using either OS for. Personally, I have not seen any significant performance degradation in a VM that has stopped me from being productive with the applications that I usually use. If you're doing video or audio editing or relying on your systems to give you 100% CPU access and full network throughput at all times, then you may possibly also want to invest in two separate machines.

Comment: @Kusalananda I only have Windows to play games. Games require a lot of performance.